# Confuse browsers in-built "find in page" feature

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, browser

I'm developing a real-time multiplayer web/browser game where players must click on words starting with a specific letter. However, it's prone to cheating as users can exploit the browser's find-in-page feature.

After researching, I discovered that preventing find-in-page is challenging. Despite implementing a solution by appending the letter "r" to each word with opacity and font-size: 0, cheating is still possible.

I'm considering a new approach: creating SVGs for each letter and mapping them to the corresponding letters in the game. This might prevent find-in-page from working effectively. Before investing significant time into this, I'd like to know if it's a viable solution. Additionally, I'm open to alternative suggestions.

Is using SVGs a practical solution to confuse find-in-page, or do you have other recommendations? I appreciate any insights.

Comment: If you embed SVG into the HTML the text in the text element is still searchable. SVG could also be the source if the img element. In that case the text is not searchable. An alternative could be to use canvas and [Drawing text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_text).

Comment: Please do add your link

Comment: https://newsgamer.harshvats.dev/ Create a game and I'll join. I took @chrwahl advice and using canvas now so you can't cheat at all.

Comment: But still using ID so I can inject: ``canvas[id^="r" i] { border:2px solid green }``

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman thanks for this. Just fixed it and now I've removed word from id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice "Free Friday" Challenge

Keeping all logic client side I would:

- Read the **text** from `<words-puzzle>` Web Component innerHTML
- process each **word** by `<news-word>` Web Component

  - reverse the word/letters
  - add decoy `<span>` to make reading HTML difficult (DOM parsing will take some time..)
  - write **letter** in a span
  - !! display the letters `direction:rtl` to confuse HTML readers even more
  - Only add a `onclick` handler when the First letter matches
- Overwrite the `<words-puzzle>` innerHTML with the new "messy" HTML

```html
<style>
  news-word {
    unicode-bidi: embed;
    direction: rtl;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  span {
    display: inline-block;
  }
</style>
<words-puzzle find="a">
  Web Components is a suite of different technologies allowing you to create reusable 
  custom elements — with their functionality encapsulated away from the rest of your 
  code — and utilize them in your web apps.
</words-puzzle>
<script>
  customElements.define("news-word", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      let word = this.getAttribute("word");
      let decoy = "<span></span>".repeat(666);
      this.innerHTML = word.split("").reverse().map(letter => {
        return decoy + `<span>${letter}</span>` + decoy;
      }).join("");
      this.removeAttribute("word"); // clean up!!
      let puzzle = this.closest("words-puzzle");
      if (puzzle.find == word[0]) {
        puzzle.h3 = (++puzzle.findcount);
        this.onclick = () => {
           this.style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen";
           puzzle.h3 = (--puzzle.findcount);
        }
      }
    }
  })
  customElements.define("words-puzzle", class extends HTMLElement {
    get find() {
      return this.getAttribute("find")
    }
    set h3(cnt) {
      this.querySelector("h3").innerHTML = `Click the ${cnt} words starting with the letter: ${this.find}`;
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      this.findcount = 0;
      setTimeout(() =>
        this.innerHTML = `<h3></h3>` +
        this.innerHTML.trim().split(" ").map(word => {
          return `<span><news-word word="${word}"></news-word></span>`
        }).join(" "))
    }
  })
</script>
```

## Version 2

Ah, now I understand what you want.

Wack in **transparent** letters to make Ctrl-F selection unreadable

```html
<style>
  news-word {
    unicode-bidi: embed;
    direction: rtl;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  span {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
  }
  .under {
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    color:transparent;
  }
</style>
<words-puzzle find="a">
  Web Components is a suite of different technologies allowing you to create reusable custom elements — with their functionality encapsulated away from the rest of your code — and utilize them in your web apps.
</words-puzzle>
<script>
  customElements.define("news-word", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      let word = this.getAttribute("word");
      this.innerHTML = word.split("").reverse().map(letter => {
        return `<span>${letter}<span class="under">a</span></span>`;
      }).join("");
      this.removeAttribute("word"); // clean up!!
      let puzzle = this.closest("words-puzzle");
      if (puzzle.find == word[0]) {
        puzzle.h3 = (puzzle.findcount++);
        this.onclick = () => this.style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen";
      }
    }
  })
  customElements.define("words-puzzle", class extends HTMLElement {
    get find() {
      return this.getAttribute("find")
    }
    set h3(cnt) {
      this.querySelector("h3").innerHTML = `Click the ${cnt} words starting with the letter: ${this.find}`;
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      this.findcount = 0;
      setTimeout(() =>
        this.innerHTML = `<h3></h3>` +
        this.innerHTML.trim().split(" ").map(word => {
          return `<span><news-word word="${word}"></news-word></span>`
        }).join(" "))
    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: I just did a page search on this page and browser highlights the words starting with "a" in your working example. Then what's the point? Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: See second version, make CTRL-F result unreadble. Just add the other 25 letters

Comment: I still believe that running a script to ignore the span and highlight the words can easily highlight words. So a normal javascripter can still cheat, right?

Comment: You said _"I want to confuse it [find-in-page]"_ Not: _make it impossible_. Cheating will always be possible, like I did with [Wordle](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/more-wordle-mordle-extending-josh-his-web-components-4li)

Comment: So can i say that using Canvas is the only way to stop cheating?

Comment: No, you just limit the number of cheaters, knowledgeable people will open your source and cheat. Less knowledgeable will dump the source in chatGPT and aks it to cheat.